# Connecting GUI with game

Tags: java, swing, applet

I am trying to build a GUI with a game class in java. I keep getting a NullPointerException and I don't know why, I thought I was passing the object "cPlayer" to the applet that then passed it to the JPanel portion (where it should compare with the cPlayer for hits or misses) but I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Is there some other way to pass the cPlayer object to the applet and then the JPanel?

```
public class gamePlay {
    public final static ComputerBoard cPlayer = new ComputerBoard();

    public static void main(String args){
        BattleshipApplet play = new BattleshipApplet();
        play.setBoard(cPlayer);

    }
}

public class BattleshipApplet extends JApplet {
    private final JButton playButton = new JButton("Play");
    private final JLabel msgBar = new JLabel("Click Play to start game");
    private BoardPanel panel;
    private ComputerBoard game;


    public BattleshipApplet(){
        playButton.addActionListener(this::playButtonClicked);  
    }

    public void init(){
        configureGui();
    }

    private void configureGui(){
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        buttons.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0,5,0,0));
        buttons.add(playButton);
        add(buttons, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        msgBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,5,5));
        add(createBoardPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(msgBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private BoardPanel createBoardPanel(){
        panel = new BoardPanel(game);
        return panel;
    }

    private void displayMessage(String msg){
        msgBar.setText(msg);
    }

    private void playButtonClicked(ActionEvent event){
        displayMessage("Game has started!");

    }

    void setBoard(ComputerBoard b){
        game = b;
    }

}

public class BoardPanel extends JPanel  {
    private static final int ROWS = 10;
    private static final int CELL_WIDTH = 28;
    private static final int PAD = 20;
    private static final Color GRID_COLOR = Color.blue;
    private static final Color CIRCLE_COLOR_HIT = Color.red;
    private static final Color CIRCLE_COLOR_MISS = Color.white;
    private static final Color TEXT_COLOR = Color.blue;
    private static final int SML_GAP = 2;
    private boolean[][] grid = new boolean[ROWS][ROWS];
    private int counter;
    private int x, y;
    private boolean gameBoardpiece;
    ComputerBoard gameBoard;


    public BoardPanel(ComputerBoard b) {
        addMouseListener((MouseListener) new MyMouse());
        counter =0;
        gameBoard = b;
        gameBoardpiece = false;
    }



    public void reset() {
        grid = new boolean[ROWS][ROWS]; // fills grid with false
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);


        // draws grid
        g.setColor(GRID_COLOR);
        for (int i = 0; i <= ROWS; i++) {
            int x1 = PAD + i * CELL_WIDTH;
            int y1 = PAD;
            int x2 = x1;
            int y2 = PAD + CELL_WIDTH * ROWS;
            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            g.drawLine(y1, x1, y2, x2);

        }

        // iterate through the grid boolean array
        // draw circles if the grid value is true.
        int w = CELL_WIDTH - 2 * SML_GAP; // width of the circle to draw
        int h = w;
        // nested for loop to go through the grid array
        for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < grid[r].length; c++) {
                if (grid[r][c]) {
                    //if was a hit
                    if(gameBoardpiece == false){
                        g.setColor(CIRCLE_COLOR_HIT);
                    }
                    //shot was a miss
                    else{
                        g.setColor(CIRCLE_COLOR_MISS);
                    }
                    int x = PAD + c * CELL_WIDTH + SML_GAP;
                    int y = PAD + r * CELL_WIDTH + SML_GAP;
                    g.fillOval(x, y, w, h);
                }
            }
        }
        //states the number of shots in the game
        g.setColor(TEXT_COLOR);
        g.drawString("Shots: "+counter, 305,300 );
    }



    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();

            if (x < PAD || y < PAD  ) {
                // clicked above or to right of grid
                return;
            }

            int r = (y - PAD) / CELL_WIDTH;
            int c = (x - PAD) / CELL_WIDTH;

            // if clicked to right or below grid.
            if (r >= ROWS || c >= ROWS) {
                return;
            }

            if(gameBoard.matchBoard(r,c) == 0){
                gameBoardpiece = true;
            }
            if(gameBoard.matchBoard(r,c) == 1){
                gameBoardpiece = false;
            }
            counter++;
            grid[r][c] = true;
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

The error message I receive is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at battleship.BoardPanel$MyMouse.mousePressed(BoardPanel.java:113)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: That NullPointerException tells you, and us, exactly what went wrong and why.  Please include its full stack trace in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The life cycle of an applet is different from the life cycle of an application.  If this applet is run in the environment that an applet is normally run in, the `main()` method will not be called.  After the context calls the constructor of the applet, the life cycle will begin with a call to the applet's `init()` method.

Thus something like the following would work better.

```
public void init(){
    ComputerBoard cPlayer = new ComputerBoard();
    setBoard(cPlayer);
    configureGui();
}
```

or perhaps doing away with the `setBoard` method altogether and writing

```
public void init(){
    game = new ComputerBoard();
    configureGui();
}
```

Comment: Great! It worked! I was really struggling with applets.